# Need to create interactive preview of JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have JSON that looks like this:

```js
data: [{
  test: {
    innertest: "2345",
    outertest: "abcd"
  },
  trans: {
    sig: "sou",
    trip: [{
      one: "2"
    }, {
      two: "3"
    }],
    otherac: "iii"
  },{
    test: {
      innertest: "uuu",
      outertest: "rrr"
    },
    trans: {
      sig: "e",
      trip: [{
        one: "9"
      },{
        two: "8"
      }],
      otherac: "eee"
    }
  }]
```

I need to create an **interactive and expandable preview** for this JSON in HTML. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: in angularjs or plain javascript

Comment: That's not [JSON](https://json.org). _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: i am using angular 2. any things is fine for me,

Comment: You mean this `$scope.your_json = ....;` -> `<div>{{your_json | json}}</div>`?

Comment: i will get like this data from response, now i need to show using html ( how we see preview in chrome )

Comment: ok, I ll try to creating boxes, preview  means i want to say, if we expend we can check  inside the test object, like that, how in google chrome (developer mode) network have preview box, like that

Comment: @mammam then forget about my suggestion it's not what you want. You should consider [angular-json-tree](https://github.com/awendland/angular-json-tree) look at [this example](https://codepen.io/timbrown81/pen/QEyZrL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the filer "json" in HTML file as :

```
<pre ng-bind="data|json"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks @chiru, this <pre> tag looks ok,, but i need to expend  if i have object, have any idea,  how i ll do?

Comment: If you want to expand then i think you may need to go with ng js tree plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter "json" provided by angular to do this;

```
{{data | json}}
```

Comment: thanks for help @Tom. but its not working, its as same like JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using AngularJS or other version, but I think you're looking for something like [json-formatter](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter), if it's AngularJS you're using.

Just add it to your app module has you would do with any other module and use the directive:

```
<json-formatter json="{my: 'json'}" open="1"></json-formatter>
```

If you're using Angular2 instead of AngularJS, maybe you can try [angular2-prettyjson](https://github.com/matiboy/angular2-prettyjson).